# QUdpSocket not receiving data on Windows but working on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, sockets, qt5, winsock, qudpsocket

I have an application in QT 5.14 which works perfectly fine on Linux (Ubuntu) however, when I try to build it on windows the QUdpSocket receiving data.

Following is the header file:

```
#ifndef MYUDPSOCKET_H
#define MYUDPSOCKET_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include "third_party/readerwriterqueue/atomicops.h"
#include "third_party/readerwriterqueue/readerwriterqueue.h"

/**
 * @brief The MyUDPSocket class
 */
class MyUDPSocket: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    /**
     * @brief MyUDPSocket : constructor
     * @param buffer : queue to keep incoming buffers stored
     */
    MyUDPSocket(moodycamel::BlockingReaderWriterQueue<QByteArray>& buffer);

    /**
     * @brief ~MyUDPSocket : destructor
     */
    ~MyUDPSocket();

    /*==========[Public Function Declarations]====================================*/
    void run();

public slots:
    /*==========[Public Slot Declarations]====================================*/
    /**
     * @brief readPackets
     * @return void
     */
    void readPackets();

private:
    QUdpSocket *udpSkt; /**< udp socket */
    moodycamel::BlockingReaderWriterQueue<QByteArray>& queue; /**< blocking queue */

};

#endif // MYUDPSOCKET_H
```

And following is the source file:

```
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include "myudpsocket.h"

MyUDPSocket::MyUDPSocket(moodycamel::BlockingReaderWriterQueue<QByteArray>& buffer)
    : queue(buffer)
{
    moveToThread(this);
    qDebug() << "Thread:" << currentThread() << "Setting up MyUDPSocket...";
}

MyUDPSocket::~MyUDPSocket()
{
    exit();
    wait();
    delete udpSkt;
    qDebug() << "MyUDPSocket Destroyed!";
}

void MyUDPSocket::run()
{
    udpSkt = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSkt->bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 56666);
    connect(udpSkt, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readPackets()));
    // Setup event loop to receive packets
    exec();
}

void MyUDPSocket::readPackets()
{
    while (udpSkt->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(udpSkt->pendingDatagramSize());
        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;

        udpSkt->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                             &sender, &senderPort);

        if(datagram.size() > 0) {
            queue.enqueue(datagram);
        }
    }
}
```

The objective of the code is simple, receive a datagram and queue it for another thread to process.

Tested this on Windows 10, however it doesn't even work with localhost. I tried using PacketSender or Microsoft UDP Sender/Receiver but no luck.

Can anyone provide any insight into why this won't work on Windows 10 but work just fine on Linux?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to shutdown **windows firewall** or allow your app through it. I had this trouble on Windows but via `QTcpSocket`. Works on Linux (Debian), macOS Catalina but not on Windows.

Comment: Shutting down Windows Firewall helped? Ok, Will try and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Disabling firewall didn't work.